# Print column using python

Tags: python, string

I´m a total newbie

infile:

```
Baby    1902
Buby    1952
Boby    1950
Daisy   1990
Dassy   1940
Dasay   1960
Rob 1960
Bob 1990
Bolob   1970
Asdf    1999
```

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

inData = open('crap3.txt')
Lina = inData.readline()
Lina = Lina.strip()
tmpFields = Lina.split('\t')
for line in inData:
  bla = tmpFields[1]
  print(bla)
```

It prints out the first birthyear ten times. I would like it to print out every year.

Comment: Refer to [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for the proper way to style Python code (Lina should not be capitalized, 4 spaces for indentation, etc). It makes your code much easier to read when you follow the style guide.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
with open('crap3.txt') as inData:
    for line in inData:
        line = line.strip()
        name, year = line.split('\t', 1)
        print(year)
```

It's good custom to use `with` when opening files. The file is then automatically closed at the end of the block.

Answer (score 4):

Move the `split` inside the loop, so that it's done for every line. The following suffices as your complete program:

```
inData = open("crap3.txt")
for line in inData:
    print(line.split()[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't doing anything with the `line` variable in the loop. Try this:

```
lines = open('crap3.txt').readlines()
for line in lines:
    bits = line.split('\t')
    print bits[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

readline read only one line. This way you iterate over the same line again and again.

use inData.readlines() or put the readline into your loop ;)